# Tomcat Private JVM

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm

What is Private JVM? I have idea on Running Multiple Tomcat Instances on Single Machine, but I would like to know more about Private JVM I already have googled for private JVM but not satisfied with the explanation there.

Comment: It seems to be cPanel specific. I guess at one point in the shared hosted model JVM process would be shared across multiple users which I find disturbing.

Comment: Where did you hear about that?

Comment: @Thilo thy google speaketh to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are talking about terminology used by MochaHost with respect to their cPanel Java/Tomcat hosting.  I cannot see where they state this in so many words, but it is clear that:

- a "shared jvm" is where your servlet runs in a tomcat instance that shares a JVM with other customers, but
- a "private jvm" is where your servlet (or servlets) run in a tomcat instance that is not shared with other customers.

The (purported) advantages of "private jvm" are listed in page linked below.  But obviously you pay more because a "private jvm" requires more hardware resources, power than the "shared jvm" version.

Note that this terminology appears to be specific to MochaHost which is why Google is not giving you good answers.

Reference:

- http://www.mochahost.com/why_private_jvm.php

Comment: Unless they have done something totally bizarre, there is going to be a 1-to-1 relationship between the JVM and the Tomcat instance.  There might be multiple of these on one machine / virtual.  The difference between private JVM and shared JVM seems to be whether you are sharing a Tomcat/JVM with other customers ... or not.  But if you really want to be sure, talk to the sales people.

Comment: so does it(Private Jvm) mean Multiple Tomcat Instances? or multiple Jvm Inside the same machine, I thought when ever we are running a java application Jvm make a new Instance of itself for each application , If I am Wrong please explain

Comment: I don't know.  Please read the last sentence of my previous comment **again**.